# События и sleep

Tags: java

Подскажите мне такое дело. Если в программе определён обработчик моего события и я запускаю `Thread.sleep(100)`, то в то  время как прога стоит на месте, может ли прийти событие моё. Они ведь асинхронные?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: может... .

Answer (score 1):

Sleep не освобождает блокировку. Так что все попытки вызывать методы, требующие этой блокировки, будут стоять в ожидании ее освобождения.

Вообще вопрос довольно размытый. Что значит "придет событие" (куда)? Что значит "стоит прога" (конкретный поток наверное все-таки)?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.Проблема решена.Я имел в виду,что:
  1. "Прийдёт событие" - объект класса,определяющего событие(моё), присылает его.
  2. "Стоит прога" - Да.Поток программы задержан через  Thread.sleep(30000).
И то,что я имел в виду своим вопросом.Если основной поток программы задержан через Thread.sleep(30000) на 30 секунд,как вы уже догадались,а до этого был запушен ещё один поток в котором создаются события и посылаются в основной(на пример) поток,скажем, каждую секунду ,то будет ли он(основной поток) получать их и обрабатывать(он ведь задержан sleep-ом).
Ответ: да.Решил её обычным тестом